# Django finds template but doesn't render it and throws out an empty HTML page

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a view in `views.py`:

```py
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        print(uploaded_file_url)

        context = {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
        }
        return render(request, 'simple_upload.html', context)

    return render(request, 'simple_upload.html')
```

Then, a url in `urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.project_index, name='project_index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.project_detail, name='project_detail'),
    path('upload/', views.simple_upload, name='upload')
]
```

And when I hit the route `/projects/upload`, instead of a form I get an empty page. However, the `simple_upload.html` route has this structure:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

<h1>H</h1>

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>

  {% if uploaded_file_url %}
    <p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{ uploaded_file_url }}">{{ uploaded_file_url }}</a></p>
  {% endif %}

  <p><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Return to home</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

You can see, I'm getting a blank [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnqAn.png).

No errors are occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. You have to write `{% block page_content %}` in the template instead of `{% block content %}`, because in the `base.html` I have this line:

```html
{% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.